High Latency due to DNS/Routing issue with Google Cloud Storage
I am currently experiencing an issue with the resolution of Cloud Storage domain from one of my servers. I have two servers hosted by different cloud providers. When resolving storage.googleapis.com on one of my servers, Google's name servers return an IP address located in Amsterdam (for example 142.250.179.187). This is unexpected because both my server and Google's datacenter are located in the US. So the request from my server goes through datacenter in Europe and back to the US resulting in a significant latency. My other server, hosted by a different provider, resolves the domain correctly (142.251.116.207) and there are no latency issues.
Here is the mtr output from the problematic server:
[14:05:28] <host1> # mtr -r -c50 storage.googleapis.com
Start: 2024-09-23T14:06:30+0000
HOST: <host1> Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- unn-169-150-216-253.datap  0.0%    50    0.5   0.3   0.2   0.5   0.1
  2.|-- unn-185-156-45-48.cdn77.c  0.0%    50    0.2   0.4   0.2   0.6   0.1
  3.|-- 50.248.117.169             2.0%    50    1.2   0.9   0.6   1.2   0.1
  4.|-- 96-87-8-62-static.hfc.com  0.0%    50    0.3   0.4   0.3   0.6   0.1
  5.|-- 108.170.231.48             0.0%    50    0.4   0.5   0.3   0.9   0.1
  6.|-- 142.251.237.112            0.0%    50    0.8   1.1   0.8   2.8   0.3
  7.|-- 216.239.62.213             0.0%    50    0.9   2.6   0.7  52.4   7.6
  8.|-- 142.251.229.31             0.0%    50    6.8   9.4   6.8  53.7   8.1
  9.|-- 216.239.49.152             0.0%    50   32.3  22.4  21.3  37.0   3.0
 10.|-- 142.251.69.70              0.0%    50   36.4  37.5  36.2  56.7   3.9
 11.|-- 142.251.69.73              0.0%    50  108.0 108.5 107.7 117.7   1.6
 12.|-- 142.251.233.60             0.0%    50  116.7 117.7 116.6 155.2   5.4
 13.|-- 142.251.236.86             0.0%    50  116.2 116.2 116.1 116.5   0.1
 14.|-- 74.125.243.119             0.0%    50  117.0 117.3 116.9 117.8   0.2
 15.|-- 142.251.48.177             0.0%    50  116.2 116.2 116.1 116.4   0.1
 16.|-- ams15s41-in-f27.1e100.net  0.0%    50  117.1 117.2 117.1 117.9   0.1

Here are some of IPs from the problematic datacenter: 169.150.216.186, 169.150.216.145. When I tried to check them using different online lookup services, some of them indicate that these are located in the US and others that they are located in Europe.
Here is the mtr output from a server in another datacenter that works fine:
[14:07:39] <host2> # mtr -r -c50 storage.googleapis.com
Start: 2024-09-23T14:08:24+0000
HOST: <host2> Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 204.74.252.193             0.0%    50    0.9   1.4   0.4   3.4   0.6
  2.|-- se-us01-s1.servers.com     2.0%    50   73.8  20.5   0.5 411.5  71.1
  3.|-- xcore-dfw1-se-r1.servers.  0.0%    50    0.6   0.6   0.4   2.0   0.4
  4.|-- xcore-dfw1-se-r2.servers.  2.0%    50    0.6   0.6   0.3   1.4   0.2
  5.|-- 173.233.144.248            0.0%    50    0.3   1.0   0.3  12.4   2.2
  6.|-- 173.233.144.235            0.0%    50    0.6   0.7   0.5   2.0   0.2
  7.|-- 216.239.50.53              0.0%    50    0.5   0.6   0.5   2.0   0.2
  8.|-- 142.250.60.238             0.0%    50    1.2   1.4   1.1   5.4   0.6
  9.|-- 216.239.63.251             0.0%    50    1.7   2.2   0.9  45.5   6.4
 10.|-- 142.251.76.47              0.0%    50    1.8   2.2   1.7  10.3   1.2
 11.|-- 216.239.43.144             0.0%    50    4.5   2.7   2.0   5.8   1.1
 12.|-- 142.250.235.151            0.0%    50    1.6   1.6   1.6   2.6   0.1
 13.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 14.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 15.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 16.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 17.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 18.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 19.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 20.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 21.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 22.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 23.|-- ???                       100.0    50    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 24.|-- rt-in-f207.1e100.net       0.0%    50    1.6   1.6   1.6   3.2   0.3

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? I would appreciate any help.

Verify your DNS settings and make use of reputable DNS servers such as Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) or Google (8.8.8.8).Flush DNS cache on your server.Check the routing path to see where latency occurs.Test DNS resolution from different geographic locations.Please refer Troubleshoot Cloud DNS for more information related to this.

You have not provided specific details, so we can only offer suggestions. After verifying your DNS server settings, contact your cloud provider. I have seen this problem caused by the cloud vendor's IP addresses being registered in Europe. If that is the case, you must either use a different "not so smart" DNS service or switch either the cloud provider region or the cloud provider itself. If you need more help, you must provide specific details on your location and network configuration.

Thanks for your answers! For security reasons I cannot share specific IP addresses. However, I checked the IPs of my server using different online tools and it shows as being located in the US. Google's DNS, that I am currently using returns an European address, while Cloudflare returns an US address. Looks like I will need to use a different DNS service.

@JohnHanley I added some more details to the post that could help

None of the details help. Using ping is almost useless. In most cases, you need to know the BGP configuration for the IP address/block. The owner of the IP address publishes/manages that information. You will need to resolve this with the provider. Based on your comments, my guess is correct. Save yourself headaches for your use case and pick a tier 1 cloud provider (Google, Azure, AWS, IBM, Oracle, etc).
